# How to create a file blob for use with Fine Uploader api

Tags: cordova, fine-uploader

I'm using the cordova-imagePicker to get a local URL on Android and I'm uploading it with the cordova-file-transfer plugin. I would like to switch to Fine Uploader so I can make use of the resumable feature but the only api method I can find takes a file blob. How do I create a suitable blob given the path to a file or is there an api in Fine Uploader that will take a path?

Comment: Not too familiar with Cordova... what exactly does your "local URL" look like? Is it a `file://...` URL or something else?

Comment: I can provide an answer in the context of Fine Uploader, but I'm afraid I'll need more information on what kind of handle on a file Cordova gives you to provide a more complete answer. Fine Uploader's `addFiles()` method takes `File`s, `<input>`s, `Blob`s, `BlobWrapper` objects, `<canvas>`es, or `CanvasWrapper`s, FYI.

Comment: On Android the path I get back from imagePicker is something like /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100MEDIA/IMAGE0158.jpg. Given that path I can't seem to find a way to create a File object that I can pass into the Fine Uploader API.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to programmatically add files to Fine Uploader via the API is the [`addFiles()`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles) function. It allows you to add `File`s, `<input>`s, `Blob`s, `BlobWrapper` objects, `<canvas>`es, or `CanvasWrappers`.

There is no way in HTML5, currently, to create a reference to a file from a path on the local file system. My suggestion is to search for ways to create an HTML5 File object (or another compatible `addFiles` parameter) in Cordova/Phone Gap. Sorry, but I have 0 experience with those.

The [FileEntry.file](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry) property seems promising.

Comment: Unfortunately the Cordova FileEntry.file returns a File object which is not the same as an html5 File blob and it gets rejected by the addFiles function. I tried hacking qq.isFile inside addFiles to accept the File object but I don't think formData.append works with the object created by FileEntry either because req.files when it gets to the server doesn't contain a valid qqfile object.

Comment: Hi @GaryHoward , Facing the same situation for file object. Have you found any solution for it?